# How do I extract a type from an array in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

Is there a way to declare a type in typescript that 'extracts' the inner type of an array?

Example:

Let's say I already have something like this in my codebase:

```typescript
export interface Cache {
    events: Event[],
    users: User[]
}
type CacheType = Event[] | User[];

//or maybe: 
//   type TypeOfProperty = T[keyof T];
//   type CacheType = TypeOfProperty<Cache>;
```

What I want is something which would be equivalent to this:

```typescript
type InnerCacheType = Event | User;
```

But without manually retyping it every time I add something to `Cache` or `CacheType`

Is this possible in Typescript?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is possible with Typescript 2.8+. You can declare an `Unpacked<T>` type as follows:

```js
type Unpacked<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : T;
```

Now you can do

```js
type InnerCacheType = Unpacked<CacheType>; // Event | User
```

This is a condensed definition of the `Unpacked` type given in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html).

Comment: type Unpacked<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : T extends ReadonlyArray<infer U> ? U : T;

this works with ReadonlyArray as well

Answer (score 60):

This could also be achieved with a type query. ie.

```
type CacheType = Event[] | User[];
type InnerCacheType = CacheType[number]; // Event | User
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0De0C+BuAsAKFEhgFEA3BAWwBc1Nc98qBPABwWgGExgALBAFVbsAvNDKUqAbQC60AD5xESGfWZtoASQB2W5F14Ch0Ufr6C2krQFcKAI2TSs0APTOx5avMXJ8QA)

If you look at this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778#issuecomment-635613358) from the ts dev team

> You're allowed to write
>
> `const t: Array<string>[number] = "hello";`
>
> as a roundabout way of writing `const t: string`

So This will always hold true.

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume that you can use TypeScript 2.1 or greater, otherwise there is no way to achieve what you're looking for.

Also, keep in mind that you're taking for granted that all the properties of the `Cache` interface will be arrays. If this is not the case, your question becomes senseless, so I will also make this assumption.

Generally speaking, `CacheType` can be written as

```
type CacheType = Cache[typeof Cache];
```

including any inherited properties. The obtained type is equivalent to `Event[] | User[]`, however extracting the array components from such union type is unfeasible.

The solution is using mapped types. The `InnerCacheType` you are looking for can be written as

```
type InnerCacheType = MappedCacheType[typeof MappedCacheType];
```

where

```
type MappedCacheType = { [P in keyof Cache]: Cache[P][0]; };
```

In fact, the last type is equivalent to

```
{ events: Event; users: User; }
```

Please notice that TypeScript keeps the names the same as the original ones.

Summarizing, without considering your use case, the way to express the component type of an array type `T` is `T[0]`.